# Writing and reading to a memory mapped file in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, memory-mapped-files

I am experimenting in OCaml to see how I can read/write a numerical array to/from a memory mapped file.

I think I'll need to use Bigarray but not sure how to write down a Bigarray array to a memory mapped file, and then read it back?

I cannot seem to find an example anywhere. I have checked the source code of Jane St. core but to no avail.

Comment: http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Bigarray.Genarray.html `map_file` ?

Comment: @Jonathan-Protzenko: Make this an answer, it seems excellent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm making this an answer (I was originally afraid that I missed your point). The OCaml library provides a mechanism for this by default, namely, the [`map_file` function from the `Bigarray.Genarray` module](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Bigarray.Genarray.html). It does precisely what you want and amounts to `mmap`'ing the file under Unix. I'm unsure about the Windows specifics.

This has the advantage of being well-supported and well-tested, as well as not requiring you to import JaneSt's Core into your project if you didn't need it already.

Comment: On a side note, is it in generally safe to mix stdlib with core code?

Comment: As long as you don't use async it should be safe. A lot of core's modules are wrappers around the corresponding stdlib modules. Check out the `Caml` module in core which wraps the whole stdlib in case you need to use it.

Answer (score 5):

Since it seems like you're interested in using core:

Here's `map_file` from their docs (https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/109.58.00/doc/core/#Bigstring)

```
val map_file : shared:bool -> Unix.file_descr -> int -> t
```

> map_file shared fd n memory-maps n characters of the data associated with descriptor fd to a bigstring. Iff shared is true, all changes to the bigstring will be reflected in the file.

You should accept the answer Jonathan creates however.